# How to configure Spring Amqp @RabbitListener not to throw exceptions when queue does not exist?

Tags: amqp, spring-amqp

This is my @RabbitLister code:

```
@RabbitListener(queues = device.*)
```

I want this listener to listen all the queues, created by devices on my broker where * is ID of device, like:`device.1`

Currently, when i start my app and queues are not created, i'm getting an exception:

```
ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=404, reply-text=NOT_FOUND - no queue 'device.*' in vhost '/'
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Wildcards/patterns in queue names are not supported by AMQP/RabbitMQ.

Devices should only send messages to exchanges with routing keys; consumers are responsible for queues not producers.

Use a `topic` exchange with routing keys `device.1` etc and bind a single queue with routing key `device.#`.

Comment: So, i should do:
1) BindingBuilder.bind("device.1").to("amq.topic").with("device.#");
2) @RabbitListener(queues = device.#)

Comment: No; you can't listen to a wildcard. Bind a single queue `commonDeviceQueue` to the topic exchange with key `device.#`; then have the devices publish to the exchange with key `device.1`, `device.2` etc. and `@RabbitListener(queues = "commonDeviceQueue")`